# Content-Type is null while posting file to web api from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, angular-http

I am trying to upload file using web api from AngularJs application. Following is my code.

```js
app.controller('RFCController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getFileDetails = function (e) {

        $scope.files = [];
        $scope.$apply(function () {

            // STORE THE FILE OBJECT IN AN ARRAY.
            for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) {
                $scope.files.push(e.files[i])
            }

        });
    };

    $scope.uploadFiles = function () {

        //FILL FormData WITH FILE DETAILS.
        var data = new FormData();

        data.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[0]);
        
        $http.post('../api/RFCService/upload', data, {
            headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            alert("sucess!");
            },
            function (response) {
                alert("error!");
            });

    }
}]);
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="image1">Image File</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFileDetail(this)" />
          
</div>
<div>
    <button ng-click="uploadFiles()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

and this is my web api. It is just to test if it throws error.

```
[Route("api/RFCService/upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostFormData()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```

This code always throws error saying unsupported media type. When I debug the web api I see that content-type is null under `Request.Content.Headers.ContentType`. I am setting the content type while calling the api. Can someone help me to correct this code?

Comment: does it work if you use content type as 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8' ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Yes tried that. still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading objects created by the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) it is important to set the content type header to `undefined`.

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function () {

    //FILL FormData WITH FILE DETAILS.
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[0]);

    $http.post('../api/RFCService/upload', data, {
        //headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
        //IMPORTANT
        headers:{'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).then(function (response) {
        alert("sucess!");
        },
        function (response) {
            alert("error!");
        });

}
```

Normally the $http service overrides the [XHR Send Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) with content type `application/json`. By setting the header to `undefined`, the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) automatically sets the content type header with the part boundary. Forcing a content type without a content boundary causes problems.

---

### Better yet — Send the File Directly

With content type `multipart/form-data` the data is [base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which adds an additional 33% overhead. Just send the file directly:

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function () {

    //FILL FormData WITH FILE DETAILS.
    //var data = new FormData();

    //data.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[0]);

    //USE file directly
    var file = $scope.file[0];

    return $http.post('../api/RFCService/upload', file, {
        //headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
        //IMPORTANT
        headers:{'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log("success!");
        return response;
    }).catch(function (errorResponse) {
        console.error("error!");
        throw errorResponse;
    });
}
```

The [XHR Send API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) accepts [file objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and creates the proper headers for them.

Also notice that the examples returns the promise from the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and properly chains after logging.

---

### Older versions of AngularJS

The AngularJS $http service, by default, sets the content type header and serializes JavaScript objects to JSON UTF-8 strings. Modern versions of the $http service detect Blob, File, and FormData objects and skip serialization<sup>[1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L298)</sup>. With older versions, configure with `transformRequest: []` to prevent serialization.

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (url, file) {

    var config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        tranformRequest: []
    };

    return $http.post(url, file, config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("success!");
        return response;
    }).catch(function (errorResponse) {
        console.error("error!");
        throw errorResponse;
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried sending file directly and setting content-type as undefined. but still facing same issue. Content-Type is showing null on the server side and returns same error.

Comment: Do I need to do any changes on Web Api method to make this work? Please look at the web api method as well

Comment: Ok. Here is how I got it working now. Following is the code. Posting the code as answer but will mark your post as answer.

Comment: Updated answer for older versions of AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is how I got it working. See call from angularjs below.

```js
 $scope.uploadFiles = function () {

        //FILL FormData WITH FILE DETAILS.
        var data = new FormData();
        var file = $scope.files[0];

        data.append("uploadedFile", file);
        
        $http({
            url: '../api/RFCService/upload',
            method: 'Post',
            data: data,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
            transformRequest: angular.identity

        }).then(function (response) {
                alert("sucess!");
                },
                function (response) {
                    alert("error!");
                });
    }
```

I had to add transformRequest. Thanks to georgeawg for pointing to right direction.

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using? Only versions prior to V1.3.7 need to override transformRequest for FormData objects. Prior to V1.3.0-beta.3 for Blob objects. Prior to V1.0.0-rc2 for File objects.